# Relationship between profit margins, historical volatility and implied volatility

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, black-scholes-merton

In a scenario where no historic data exists in an option market, how would one come up with implied volatility for pricing of options, under the Black-Scholes-Merton model?

My professor has suggested using realised volatility from the stock prices and incorporating a profit margin. Is there some relationship that exists between implied volatility, realised volatility and profit margins?

For example, if we had a realised volatility of 10% and were aiming for a profit margin of 5% on writing options, what would we use as $\sigma$ in the BSM model?

Comment: I think your professor is suggesting you would calculate the BSM price C for a vol of 10%, but then sell the options for 1.05*C, i.e. add a 5% "markup" (just like shop owners add a markup to their cost).

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Using Black-Scholes, if the company has bonds, you can also get an implied equity volatility from the bond yields and capital structure of the company.

Comment: @noob2 Would a similar relationship hold for hedging delta? In other words, after calculating delta with the realised volatility, should I multiply this by some constant?

Comment: Perhaps we could take the "marked up price" of the option and compute the IV from that (clearly will be higher than 10%) then use that IV from now on to compute deltas for delta hedging.